# ASP.Net MVC 3 - Single controller, single action and multiple views

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I would like to know what is the best method to have an action return different views. Let's say you have a form for submitting data, but you want to choose the view depending on what data is submitted. I would prefer not using a redirection, since there is stuff I want to be displayed in the data that is posted.

An example of this would be to have an Edit form that displays a Details view when clicking on  Save, but without using a redirection.

I know this could be done with a single view containing a conditional if statement to display this or that, but there are cases where I would prefer my views to stay simple without too much code in them. If the controller could just choose the view to display once the data is posted, this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *should* be using the Post/Redirect/Get pattern. You can still "display stuff." You can pass an ID on the URI and look them up in the new `GET` or use `TempData`.

Attempting to circumvent Post/Redirect/Get is *not* a good solution. Among other things, it breaks the back button.

Comment: "Should", why? Why add this extra round-trip to the database if it is not necessary? It would break the back button? Let's say you have an error in the data you submitted, all will happen is Post instead of Post/Redirect/Get, and the back button will still work. Why not do the same if the data is valid? All is needed is a different views depending on the validity of the data.

Comment: Attempting to "optimize" away one DB read after a successful edit is silly. Do you *really* think that's the slowest part of your app? As for Post/Redirect/Get, why are you asking me to restate the purpose of the pattern when so much has been written already? There are a number of problems with what you propose; please take the time to research the pattern.

Comment: Well, of course that database accesses are the slowest part of my app; it means access to data on the disk and over the network. But thanks, I'll do some research about that pattern when I am a bit less in a rush.

Comment: @Craig_Stuntz Did you really mean the Back button, or did you mean the Reload button? Because I can see a problem in some cases if someone reposts the form.

Comment: Both back and reload are problematic. Again, please see the published information on P/R/G -- there's no reinvent the wheel by explaining it in an SO comment. Regarding DB performance, measure; don't guess. Yes, DB access can be slow, but this is typically a factor when displaying a list of information -- which happens a lot in a typical app -- rather than when displaying *one record* after you post -- which happens relatively less frequently. Profile before you "optimize."

Answer (score 6):

There is an overload to the `View()` method that allows you to specify the name of the View you want to return.

```
return View("DetailsView", model);
```

Comment: However, he *should not* use this for the purpose stated in his question!

Comment: Thanks for the info to both of you. Now, I can do an educated choice.